# How to console an observable data in container component

Tags: angular8, angular-observable, ngrx-store-8.0

In my component I am getting data from store, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

        this.appUserName = this.store.pipe(select(subscribe.getAppUserName));
        this.store.dispatch(new actions.LoadTranslationIds());
        this.data = this.store.pipe(select(subscribe.getTranslationIds));

    }
```

after assigned I am trying to print the "this.data" in 'ngChanges' like:

```
ngOnChanges() {
     console.log('trans id', this.data);
}
```

But `ngOnChanges` itself not triggering. I am not able to console the data what i receives. what is wrong with my code? or what would be the correct approach?

I am not using "subscribe" approach here.

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges` only be called when any data-bound property of a directive changes.

Why don't you subscribe it.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Comment: that's for getting `@input` as data, I am looking for container/smart component solution

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
this.data = this.store.pipe(select(subscribe.getTranslationIds)).pipe(tap((val) => console.log(val)));
```

it will work for you!